# Creating an `Eigen::Matrix` from two raw vectors

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there a way to create an Eigen::MatrixXd where each column comes from a different 'raw' vector.  For example, I would like take this code from the documentation:

```
int array[8];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) array[i] = i;
cout << "Column-major:\n" << Map<Matrix<int,2,4> >(array) << endl;
```

and change it to

```
int array1[4];
int array2[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) array1[i] = i;
for(int i = 4; i < 8; ++i) array2[i-4] = i;
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> m(nullptr, 4, 2);
m.col(0) = array1;
m.col(1) = array2;
cout << "Column-major:\n" << m << endl;
```

Or something similar... is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If that's only two arrays, you can abuse strides:

```
Map<MatrixXd,0,OuterStride<> > m(array1, 4, 2, OuterStride<>(array2-array1));
```

Otherwise you can easily craft something in 10 lines of code following the examples of [NullaryExr](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_NullaryExpr.html). Basically, all you need is a class:

```
class my_mat_type_func {
  std::vector<double*> m_column_pointers;
  Eigen::Index rows;
public:
  const double& operator() (Index row, Index col) const {
    return m_column_pointers[col][row];
  }
  // custom API to fill data, resize, etc.
};
```

and wrap it as a `NullaryExpr`.